# Есть ли возможность слушать с youtube только аудио(музыку)?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Необходимо сделать приложение для прослушивая музыки на youtube(читать только аудио дорожку). Я еще не сильно ознакомился с API под андройд но мне кажется что там такой возможности нет. Есть какие-то сторонние библиотеки или возможности? Без использования сторонних серверов.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант,  с помощью [ListenToYouTube](http://www.listentoyoutube.com) или подобного сервиса, "вытянуть" аудиодорожку и скачать отдельным файлом.